# Initializer for the numeration with non-fixed type

Tags: c++, enums

The standard says at `7.2/5 [dcl.enum]`:

> If the underlying type is not fixed, the type of each enumerator prior
>   to the closing brace is determined as follows:
>
> (5.1) — If an initializer is specified for an enumerator, the
>   constant-expression shall be an integral constant expression (5.20).
>   If the expression has unscoped enumeration type, the enumerator has
>   the underlying type of that enumeration type, otherwise it has the
>   same type as the expression.
>
> (5.2) — If no initializer is specified for the first enumerator, its
>   type is an unspecified signed integral type.
>
> (5.3) — Otherwise the type of the enumerator is the same as that of
>   the preceding enumerator unless the incremented value is not
>   representable in that type, in which case the type is an unspecified
>   integral type sufficient to contain the incremented value. If no such
>   type exists, the program is ill-formed.

So, all the following cases are covered by `5.1` and `5.2`:

**I.** `enum A { x = 4 }; //case 1, initializer was specified`

**II.** `enum B { x, y };  //case 2, initializer was not specified.`

**III.**

```
enum C { x = 5 };

enum D { y = x }; // case 1, y had unscoped enumeration type.
```

**IV.**

```
enum struct C { x = 5 };

enum D { y = 0, x = C::x }; // even integral constant expression must have integral
                            // or unscoped enumeration type, not 'C
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89ccda7dc960346d)

I'd like to look at the `5.3` case in action. Why didn't case `IV` even compile?

Comment: Case IV doesn't compile because scoped enums are not integral constant expressions. For 5.3, consider `enum E { x = INT_MAX, y };`

Comment: @T.C. Interesting example. TY. But the program should be ill-formed if it contained the `enum E { x = LONG_LONG_MAX, y };` because the incremented `x` wasn't represented by any integral-type, but it wasn't. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/581e4e94b9558db4 It's just a warning.

Comment: If a program is ill-formed with a diagnostic required, then the implementation must emit a diagnostic (GCC does so, with a warning), but there's no requirement that translation/execution must fail. Just because you get a warning rather than an error doesn't mean the program is not ill-formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **7.2/5** Following the closing brace of an enum-specifier, each enumerator has the type of its enumeration.

So within the definition of `D`, `C::x` is of type `C`.

> **5.19/3** An *integral constant expression* is an expression of integral or **unscoped** enumeration type...

Emphasis mine. So `C::x` is not an integral constant expression, and cannot serve as an initialiser for an enumerator.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of introducing scoped enumerations into the language was to prevent implicit conversions to the underlying type. So in your failing example there's no way to implicitly convert from a `C::x` to whatever integral type the underlying type of `D` is.

Add the appropriate casts, and your code compiles.

```
#include <type_traits>

enum struct C { x = 5 };

enum D 
{ 
    y = 0, 
    x = static_cast<std::underlying_type<C>::type>(C::x)
};
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4111fb66e589c2cd)